# Largest integer which will work in this flash application (scratch)

Tags: forms, flash, testing, input, mit-scratch

https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/26664091/#fullscreen

I was playing monopoly and I used the above flash application. Now I'm curious what will be the largest integer which will fit in the 'player 2 money' field? I tried to input 6009000 manually using a macro, but I could keep running that macro for days without getting any real answer. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One of those: **int.MAX_VALUE** = 2147483647 **uint.MAX_VALUE** = 4294967295 or **Number.MAX_VALUE** ~= 1.79e+308

Answer (score 0):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVDYt.jpg

using the code in the image at the link above, I found the max integer of Scratch to be 1.79e308. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The highest number that Scratch can handle is [image: 2^1023 ≈ 1.79e308], which is due to the fact that Scratch uses JavaScript, in which [image: 2^1023 ≈ 1.79e308] is the biggest possible number.

---

To find this, I used this code and edited the 1023:
[image]